# How to dispaly values in HTML element from ajax api call

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, api

I've json response from ajax api call. I get expected results in console.log, but i want to display each value from response to html elements.

```
Scheduled<br>
Driver:<br>
Passenger:<br>

Active<br>
Driver:<br>
Passenger:
```

Working code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    asyn: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "/rate/current/gettrips",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    callback: 'callback',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
      //console.log(result)
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result))
      for (var propertyName in obj) {
        console.log(propertyName + ":");
        for (var internalPropertyName in obj[propertyName]) {
          console.log(internalPropertyName + ":" + obj[propertyName][internalPropertyName]);
        }
      }

    }
  });

});
```

API response in JSON as following

```
{
  "scheduled": {
    "driver_count": 1,
    "passenger_count": 1
  },
  "active": {
    "driver_count": 0,
    "passenger_count": 0
  }
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Display values in html elements as in html code
In Schedule
Display Driver & Passenger counts same for 
Active

Comment: So, do you mean that 10 should appear in total schedule drivers and 60 should appear in total schedule passengers, and similar for the active drivers for passengers?

Comment: If you want something to work, what keeps you from writing the appropriate code?

Comment: @31piy yes, it is

Comment: ```result``` is basically a JSON object converted by jQuery for you. You don't need to do this:
```var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is just to show the values in HTML elements, here is one way to do that. You don't need loop for it.

Simply use the ID selector to select the appropriate element, and use the `text()` method on it to set the inner text of that element.

See the following demo:

```js
const jsobj = {
  "scheduled": {
    "driver_count": 10,
    "passenger_count": 60
  },
  "active": {
    "driver_count": 40,
    "passenger_count": 90
  }
}

$('#total_sh').text(jsobj.scheduled.driver_count + jsobj.scheduled.passenger_count);
$('#schedule-driver').text(jsobj.scheduled.driver_count);
$('#schedule-pass').text(jsobj.scheduled.passenger_count);

$('#total_ac').text(jsobj.scheduled.driver_count + jsobj.active.passenger_count);
$('#Active-driver').text(jsobj.active.driver_count);
$('#Active-pass').text(jsobj.active.passenger_count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="more" href="javascript:;">
  Total Schedule: <span id="total_sh"></span>
  <p>Drivers : <span id="schedule-driver"></span></p>
  <p>passengers : <span id="schedule-pass"></span></p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="more" href="javascript:;">
  Total Active: <span id="total_ac"></span>
  <p>Drivers : <span id="Active-driver"></span></p>
  <p>passengers :<span id="Active-pass"></span></p>
</div>
```